# Create an array of refs (Maximum update depth exceeded)

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps and I am rendering multiple markers using array.map(). I also have a carousel which is displaying some pictures and info about each marker.

Basically whenever a user clicks on an item in the carousel, the map zooms in to that marker and displays the callout by calling the following function.

```
markers[index].showCallout()
```

which will display the call out for that marker. So I need to populate the array with refs so that I can pass in the index which will show the callout when the user moves the carousel.

To start I created an array which will hold some state.

```
const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
```

Here is the array.map function which generates all the markers on the map.

```
{searchResults.map((marker, index) => {
          return (
            <MapView.Marker
              key={marker.key}
              ref={(m) => {
                setMarkers((markers) => [[...markers], m]);
              }}
              onPress={() => onMarkerPress(marker, index)}
              coordinate={{
                latitude: marker.geopoint.latitude,
                longitude: marker.geopoint.longitude,
              }}>
              <Callout>
                <Text>{marker.price}</Text>
              </Callout>
            </MapView.Marker>
          );
        })}
```

The error that I am getting is "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

because I am trying to populate the array using this line.

```
ref={(m) => {setMarkers((markers) => [[...markers], m])}}
```

Not sure if there is another way to do this.

The below trick seems to work fine if you're using class components

```
ref={ref => this.state.markers[index] = ref}
```

but I am using functional components in my app.

Here's the entire code

```
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  {
    /************ Array for Rendering Items in Carousel */
  }

  const searchResults = [
    {
      key: '1',
      photographerURL:
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/598917/pexels-photo-598917.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
      price: 100,
      photographerName: 'Brittany',
      geopoint: {latitude: 38.8929372, longitude: -77.0025119},
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      photographerURL:
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1264210/pexels-photo-1264210.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
      price: 200,
      photographerName: 'Franklin',
      geopoint: {latitude: 38.8963932, longitude: -77.0030197},
    },
    {
      key: '3',
      photographerURL:
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/243757/pexels-photo-243757.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
      price: 50,
      photographerName: 'Bryan',
      geopoint: {latitude: 38.8925739, longitude: -76.9987113},
    },
  ];


  /**
   * Function to animate map.
   * When the user moves the carousel, the map will zoom in to
   * the region where that photographer is
   */

  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const [carouselRef, setCarouselRef] = useState([]);
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);

  console.log(markers);

  /**
   * Zooms in on the region whenever the carousel item is changed
   */
  const onCarouselItemChange = (index) => {
    let location = searchResults[index];
    {
      mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
        latitude: location.geopoint.latitude,
        longitude: location.geopoint.longitude,
        //Zoom Level
        latitudeDelta: 0.01,
        longitudeDelta: 0.01,
      });
    }
    //markers[index].showCallout();
  };

  /**
   * When a user clicks on the marker, the carousel jumps
   * to that particular item
   */
  const onMarkerPress = (location, index) => {
    mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
      latitude: location.geopoint.latitude,
      longitude: location.geopoint.longitude,
      //Zoom Level
      latitudeDelta: 0.01,
      longitudeDelta: 0.01,
    });
    carouselRef.snapToItem(index);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/**************** Google Maps *************** */}
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        ref={mapRef}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        showsUserLocation
        followsUserLocation
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 38.8929372,
          longitude: -77.0025119,
          //Zoom Level
          latitudeDelta: 0.01,
          longitudeDelta: 0.03,
        }}>
        {searchResults.map((marker, index) => {
          return (
            <MapView.Marker
              key={marker.key}
              //ref={(m) => [setMarkers((markers) => [...markers, m])]}
              onPress={() => onMarkerPress(marker, index)}
              coordinate={{
                latitude: marker.geopoint.latitude,
                longitude: marker.geopoint.longitude,
              }}>
              <Callout>
                <Text>{marker.price}</Text>
              </Callout>
            </MapView.Marker>
          );
        })}
      </MapView>
      {/***************** Carousel ***********/}
      <Carousel
        ref={(c) => {
          setCarouselRef(c);
        }}
        data={searchResults}
        horizontal
        containerCustomStyle={styles.carousel}
        onSnapToItem={(index) => onCarouselItemChange(index)}
        layout={'default'}
        //layoutCardOffset={`50`}
        sliderWidth={screenWidth}
        itemWidth={screenWidth * 0.8}
        itemHeight={400}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <Item
            photographerName={item.photographerName}
            uri={item.photographerURL}
            price={item.price}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
  },
  carousel: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    marginBottom: '5%',
  },
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `ref={(m) => {setMarkers((markers) => [...markers, m])}}`? Note the lack of `[]` in `...markers`

Comment: I gave that a shot and it returns the same error. It fills the array but it calls setState 300 times and then blows up.

Comment: maybe somethig else is causing the re rendering?

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is old, but I found the solution.
It's due to the functional components architecture in react-native.
The function is called multiple times, so the limit of `setState` is rapidly reached.

To avoid this, add:

```
const [markersLoaded,setMarkersLoaded]=useState(false)
```

Then:

```
ref={(m) => {
if (!markersLoaded)
            {
             setMarkers((markers) => [[...markers], m]);
             setMarkersLoaded(true);}
           }}
```